# Не устанавливается пакет eolica/nova-locale-switcher

Tags: php, laravel, composer

При установке пакета eolica/nova-locale-switcher выводится

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                  
  The "https://nova.laravel.com/packages.json" file could not be downloade  
  d: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Try again                
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Try  
   again
```

Ubuntu 20.04.1
php 7.4.3
laravel 7

Но это связано, на мой взгляд не с Laravel. Так как при команде composer self-update выводится та же ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего вы неверно пытаетесь установить пакет при помощи Composer`a

Приведите файл `package.json` в состояние до установки вашего пакета, а затем в корневой папке проекта Laravel используйте команду

```
composer require eolica/nova-locale-switcher
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в выделении памяти для скрипта. Решилось так:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/bin/composer require <nazvanie/paketa>
```